# R 1000+ .CSV files merging and frequency analysis

Tags: r, csv, data-analysis

so I'm back with an even more adventurous approach for my thousands of .CSV files manipulation with R. I can import, merge every ten files, rename columb headers, save new .CSV etc, but the result is still too cumbersome to manipulate analytically.

What I need is; every 10 files put into a matrix OR merged into a single file (see below for file example). The columns are *Frequency*, *Channel A* (and later *Channel B*). Simply *F*, *A*, and *B*, and the *F* values are the same for every file (hence I was thinking `matrix`). In the end I'll end up with headers

```
| *F* | *A1* | *B1* | *A2* | *B2* | *A3* | *B3* |
```

etc... to 10.

Inside of the `matrix`/`bind_col` loop, is it possible before `wrie.csv` to do some math functions on the values *A1-10*? A few new columns for **Average** and **Mean** for each *Frequency*. I need others too but I'll sort that myself.

```
    +------------+-------------+
    |  Frequency |  Channel A  |
    |    (MHz)   |    (dBV)    |
    +------------+-------------+
       0.00000000,-27.85117000
       0.00007629,-28.93283000
       0.00015259,-32.89576000
       0.00022888,-43.54568000
    ---
    Continued...
    ---
      19.99977312,-60.59710000
      19.99984941,-48.58142000
      19.99992571,-43.29094000
```

Thanks for you time, I know I've spent too much debugging and now I'm looking for a more elegant method.
PS: How's my formatting? Table and .CSV style blunder!

Comment: I forgot to include naming the `write.csv` file after the files read from. Eg: *filename~testJ~1* to *...~testJ~10*. `write.csv` file name = filename~testJ.csv. How awkward!

Comment: Don't use comments for amending your questions. Use the `[edit]` link. That's what it's there for, and using it raises the quality of the question. You say "you are back". Does that mean there is more context in some other unlinked question that you expect answers to look up? You say you have code you have been debugging, but you offer not code.

Comment: Thanks @42-. I had to comment from a mobile device only minuets later, edit wouldn't work properly. I'm back for more as a new user, found threads and answers very helpful last time around. I didn't insert code, wanted a fresh start with an example of better structure. Code to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to answer without a better example of what each file looks like, and what you want your output to be, as well as some example code.

Are the files small enough that you can load all 1000 at once?

Something like the following is where I would start if it were me.

```
library(data.table)

filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".csv$")

list_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(filenames))

i <- 1
for (file in filenames){
  list_data[[i]] <- fread(file)
  i <- i + 1
}

dat <- rbindlist(list_data, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

After that, you can use all of the useful data.table features.

```
dat[, .(meanA = mean(A), stdevA = sd(A)), by = Frequency]
```

Comment: An `lapply` would simplify the for loop, and could be done in parallel with `mclapply`, but I thought this would be clearer as to what it was actually doing.